# Parsing JSON to Kibana using Grok Filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I want to parse a JSON file like this

```
{
"Format": "IDEA0",
"ID": "2b03eb1f-fc4c-4f67-94e5-31c9fb32dccc",
"DetectTime": "2022-01-31T08:16:12.600470+07:00",
"EventTime": "2022-01-31T01:23:01.637438+00:00",
"Category": ['Intrusion.Botnet'],
"Confidence": 0.03,
"Note": "C&C channel, destination IP: 192.168.1.24 port: 8007/tcp score: 0.9324",
"Source": [{'IP4': ['192.168.1.25'], 'Type': ['CC']}]
}
```

Using this Logstash Conf

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/StratosphereLinuxIPS/output/*.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "test-test"
                user => "***"
                password => "***"
        }
        stdout{}
}
```

But i can't get a proper output in Kibana, the JSON is not separated correctly

[Kibana Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaRJo.png)

Is there anyone who can help me? any help will i appreciate

Thank You !
Adabi

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the JSON filter, but your input plugin: `file` has a [`delimiter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-delimiter) parameter which defaults to `\n`, so one line in your file will produce one document. You can change the `delimiter` (maybe to `},\n`, but depends on how you are writing the files) or use the [multiline codec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.8/multiline.html)'s some wisdom) or (even better) write a single JSON on a single line.

Comment: Hi @dcolazin, can you give me a hint about what should I write in my logstash conf? I'm still confused by what you saying + I'm a newbie to this grok syntax, thanks!

Comment: @AdabiRaihanMuhammad did you try to change the delimiter?

Comment: Hi @dcolazin, I've already done some searching how to change delimiter but no luck, what I already tried is convert this JSON to a single line, but the result are the same